# Automatically version JAR's in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, version

Is there any functionality in Eclipse (similar to Visual Studio), to automatically tag the JAR's with increasing version?

I googled for this first, but didn't find any specific answer.

Thanks!

Comment: You should use a thing like Maven, Gradle or Ant to do such a thing.

Comment: Agreed with khmarbaise:  Eclipse has built in support for Ant, we're using it to do tagging of our jar files.

Comment: I indeed plan to switch soon to fully Buildr or Gradle based build, but for now looking to a quick solution for this. Is there any Ant sample file I can use for exporting to JAR and tagging? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Ant in the end, and now switch to Maven to do the same.